# Queueable Apex Job: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, Owner ID: owner cannot be blank: [OwnerId]

Tags: apex, queueable-apex

I keep getting an error on this line when trying to update the lead list. "INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, Owner ID: owner cannot be blank: [OwnerId]"

`leadsToUpdate.add(new Lead(OwnerId = l.OwnerId, Id = l.Id, Latitude= lat,Longitude = lng));`

and/or this line:

`update leadsToUpdate;`

I am able to update all the other objects I am passing this queueable job, but for some reason "Lead" keeps failing. I've tried setting the OwnerId and leaving it blank like the other objects, but still failing.

The weird thing is that it will update the leads in the final batch. As you can see I am taking into account that queueable apex can have a max of 100 callouts. All of the initial batches will fail with the above error, but the final batch of leftover leads is getting updated without issue.

Any help or advice would be appreciated!

```
public without sharing class GoogleMapsApiQueueable implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {

    public List<SObject> recordList;

    public GoogleMapsApiQueueable(List<SObject> recordList) {
        this.recordList = recordList;
    }

    public void execute(QueueableContext context){
       
        List<Lead> leadsToUpdate = new List<Lead>();

        Integer sentCount = 0;
        Boolean hitLimit = false;

        for(SObject so: recordList){
            if(Limits.getCallouts() == Limits.getLimitCallouts()){
                hitLimit = true;
                break;
            }
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            String urlParameters = '';
            Lead l;
            if(so.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName() == 'Lead'){
                l = [SELECT Id, Street, City, State, PostalCode, Country, OwnerId FROM Lead WHERE Id = :so.Id];
                if(String.isNotBlank(l.Street)){
                    urlParameters += '+'+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(l.Street, 'UTF-8');
                }
                if(String.isNotBlank(l.City)){
                    urlParameters += '+'+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(l.City, 'UTF-8');
                }
                if(String.isNotBlank(l.State)){
                    urlParameters += '+'+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(l.State, 'UTF-8');
                }
                if(String.isNotBlank(l.PostalCode)){
                    urlParameters += '+'+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(l.PostalCode, 'UTF-8');
                }
                if(String.isNotBlank(l.Country)){
                    urlParameters += '+'+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(l.Country , 'UTF-8');
                }
            }

            String url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+urlParameters+'&key='+apiKey;

                req.setEndpoint(url);
                req.setMethod('GET');

                Http http = new Http();
                HttpResponse res = http.send(req);

                Double lat;
                Double lng;
                try{
                    Map<String, Object> m =   (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
                    List<Object> resultsMap = (List<Object>)m.get('results');

                    for(Object obj : resultsMap){
                        Map<String,Object> data = (Map<String,Object>)obj;
                        Map<String,Object> geometry = (Map<String,Object>)data.get('geometry');
                        for(String key : geometry.keySet()){
                            if(key == 'location'){
                                Map<String,Object> location = (Map<String,Object>)geometry.get('location');
                                lat = (Double)location.get('lat');
                                lng = (Double)location.get('lng');
                            }
                        }
                    }


                }catch(Exception ex){
                    System.debug('<---Exception--->' + ex);
                }
                if(lat != null && lng != null){
                    if(so.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName() == 'Lead'){
                        leadsToUpdate.add(new Lead(OwnerId = l.OwnerId, Id = l.Id, Latitude= lat,Longitude = lng));
                    }
                }
                sentCount++;
        }

        try{
            if(!leadsToUpdate.isEmpty()){
                System.debug('<---leadsToUpdate--->' + leadsToUpdate);
                update leadsToUpdate;
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.debug('<---Exception GoogleMapsApiQueueable--->' + ex);
        }

        if(hitLimit){
            System.debug('<---hitLimit--->');
            System.debug('<---recordList.size()--->' + recordList.size());
            System.debug('<---sentCount--->' + sentCount);
            for(Integer i = 0; i < sentCount; i++){
                //System.debug('<---recordList[i]' + recordList[i]);
                recordList.remove(0);
            }
            System.enqueueJob(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what is the specific error? Also, strip out [edit] your post to only include the lead logic as the rest seems irrelevant to your issue and there's too much to wade through

Comment: The specific error was in the title. I moved to the body as well. Code block has been updated to remove extraneous details.